# Interpreting ICC in 3-level logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I've run a 3-level logistic regression in STATA- level one is maternal health clinics (N=200), level 2 is the primary health care centres(N=41) which run the clinics and level 3 is the district(N=8).

I understand what the ICC is and how to calculate it but just need help interpreting the STATA output which is below. The top is the level 3 district ICC, but the second which includes the primary health care centre is what I'm findng confusing to interpret.

Thanks!

[image: ICC output]

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you find confusing - obviously the interpretation is that the ICCs between .3785335 and .8926868 are reasonably compatible with the data while .6923978 is the most compatible. But I guess your problem is elsewhere. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Apologies, I'll try to be more specific.